# Python Multiprocessing, passing files as deepcopies?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deep-copy

I have a very parallelizable task: given an ID, look for it in a graph structure, look to the ids it is pointing to and compute a mean of their values.

I'm using python multiprocessing for this task, I have an object called `graph` which summarizes the properties I am interested in and the hierarchy structure.

Using python multiprocessing in a very naive way:

```
processes = []

for i in range(10):
    currDataset = getOneTenthofDataset(fullDataset)
    process = multiprocessing.process(name='name', target=func1, args=(currDataset, graph))
    processes.append(process)
    process.start() 

for p in processes:              
     p.join()

def func1(dataset, graph):
    ...
    for each row of dataset query on graph, update current row accordingly
    save dataset to file (I don't need to return the splitted datasets!)
```

I see almost no speedup in computational time (and I think this might be due to the fact that queries on the graph are queuing and not being done in parallel?)
So what I did was

```
def func2(dataset, graph):
    localGraph = copy.deepcopy(graph)
    .. same code as func1 ..
```

This lead to a mysterious and strange mistake! Indeed not all the processes ended correctly, but only 1/3 to 1/2 of them and each time different ones end correctly. Avoiding the deepcopy instead everything works fine.
Another strange behaviour is that the processes that do not get to the end do not throw any error, they just stop executing and don't go to the instruction following the deepcopy!
In the end, the program terminates without any error

Comment: Are you on Windows or a unix-like system?

Comment: Unix: Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiprocessing` needs to serialize/deserialize any parameters you pass to the function. if your dataset is large, that will be expensive. On forking systems, (not Windows!), you can leverage the fact that subprocesses get a copy-on-write view of the parent's memory and skip the copy. Put `fullDataset` and `graph` somewhere where `func1` can find it without it being passed as a parameter, like the module's `global` namespace. Since your example code is already at module level, I assume you've already done that. Replace `getOneTenthOfDataset` with `getDatasetSlice` (I just made that up of course) and you are good to go.

```
processes = []

for i in range(10):
    process = multiprocessing.process(name='name', target=func1, args=(i,))
    processes.append(process)
    process.start() 

for p in processes:              
     p.join()

def func1(i):
    dataset = getDatasetSlice(i)
    graph # Its already in module namespace
    ....
    for each row of dataset query on graph, update current row accordingly
    save dataset to file (I don't need to return the splitted datasets!)
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the deepcopy was failing and no errors were thrown, but this totally solved my problem, good to know!